# Unable to load the pictures from MySQL in laravel on google cloud app engine

Tags: mysql, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I deploy a laravel project on google cloud app engine everting is working fine expect 'pictures' that am fetching from products table in MySQL database.
The images are broken, all the thing are working fine on the localhost.

Here's my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php73

handlers:
    - url: /assets
      static_dir: public/assets


    - url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
      static_files: public/uploads
      upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

runtime_config:
    document_root: public

env_variables:
    ## Put production environment variables here.
    APP_KEY: Already Get this from .env
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    SESSION_DRIVER: cookie


    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_DATABASE: ufurnitures
    DB_USERNAME: ufurnitures
    DB_PASSWORD: Already set the pass
    DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/ufurniture:us-central1:ufurnitures

    ## To use Stackdriver logging in your Laravel application, copy
    ## "app/Logging/CreateStackdriverLogger.php" and "config/logging.php"
    ## into your Laravel application. Then uncomment the following line:
    # LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver


beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: ufurniture:us-central1:ufurnitures
```

I have an 'uploads' folder in a public directory where pictures are getting saved.

[image: Here's the image for reference of upload folder]

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: public/uploads
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

To this!

```
- url: /uploads
  static_dir: public/uploads
```

And hurry it worked! ^_^